# laravel eloquent : Increments visits column by one for every visits

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, increment

I have model for my post in my site.My post model has a column that stores visits.when user visit my post should increments by 1.
I exactly knows how to do this, but my problem is when I increment it by one in my model, it's increments by 2!!!!!

I wrote this code in my controller:

```
$new_post_inst = Post::where('id','=',$id)->first();
$new_post_inst->increment('visit');
```

This is my controller:

```
    public function get_id($id) {

    // cat

    $cat = Category::join('catrelations', 'catrelations.idcat', '=', 'categories.id')->orderBy('categories.id', 'ASC')->get();

    // menu

    $nav = Nav::orderBy('index', 'DESC')->get();

    $post = Post::find($id);

    $setting = Settings::find(1);

    $comments = Comment::where('post_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

    $get_reply = array();

    $get_reply_id = array();

    //$counter = 0;

    //var_dump($comments);

    foreach ($comments as $comment) {

        $reply = Reply::where('parentId', '=', $comment->id)->get();

        if (!$reply->isEmpty()) {

            //$arr_reply[$comment->id] = $reply;

            //echo $comment->id.' has reply!!!!!<br>';

            //$reply_parent_id = $comment->id;

            $counter = 0;

            foreach ($reply as $replying) {

                $get_reply[$comment->id][$counter] = Comment::where('id', '=', $replying->comment_id)->get();

                //$comment_reply_id = $replying->comment_id;

                //$reply_arr = array();

                //$reply_arr[$comment->id] =  $comment_reply_id;

                //echo 'The reply is: '.$comment_reply_id.'<br>';

                foreach ($get_reply[$comment->id][$counter] as $key => $value) {

                    //($value->text);

                    $get_reply_id[] = $value->id;
                }

                $counter++;
            }

            //$counter++;


        }
    }

    $post_owner_info = User::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'image', 'desc')->find($post->user_id);

    $arr = array();

    $arr['comments'] = $comments;

    $arr['post'] = $post;

    //$arr['reply'] = $reply;

    //var_dump($get_reply);

    //var_dump($get_reply_id);
    $new_post_inst = Post::where('id','=',$id)->first();
    $new_post_inst->increment('visit');

    return View::make('blogsingle', compact('arr'))->with('setting', $setting)->with('post', $post)->with('nav', $nav)->with('get_reply', $get_reply)->with('get_reply_id', $get_reply_id)->with('cat', $cat)->with('post_owner_info', $post_owner_info);
}
```

And this is my Post model:

```
   class Post extends Eloquent 
{
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->belongstomany('Category');
    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your full controller and model to?

Comment: Have you tried : $new_post_inst->increment('visit', 1);

Answer (score 3):

you can try like this

```
$new_post_inst = Post::where('id','=',$id)->first();
$new_post_inst->increment('visit',1);
```

Comment: I have tried :$new_post_inst->increment('visit',1); right now but that's not the answer.

Comment: I have 75 visits saved in my DB, But after I it still the problem remains and new I have 77 visits in my DB.

Comment: can you please check is there double redirection?

Comment: How can I find if I have?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$new_post_inst = Post::where('id','=',$id)->first();
$new_post_inst->visit+=1;
$new_post_inst->save();
```

OR this:

```
$new_post_inst = Post::where('id','=',$id)->first();
$new_post_inst->update(array('visit' => $new_post_inst->visit+1));
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of theme working. I don't know why it always increments by two!!!! Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I searched around for a little bit and this could be the favicon icon that is making a second request. How did you declare the favicon? Or maybe you could remove it to try and see if it is indeed the favicon?